# MATLAB to Python, convert a vector mathematical expression

Tags: python, matlab

How would I convert this code from MATLAB to Python?

MATLAB:

```matlab
function out = f(x)
x1 = x(1);
x2 = x(2);
out = [x1+2*x2-2;x1^2+4*x2^2-4];
```

Python?

```py
fx = np.array([[x1+2*x2-2], [x1^2+4*x2^2-4]])
```

`x1` and `x2` are in a list?  and the position?

```py
x =[]
x1 = x[0]
x2 = x[1]
```

I don't know if this is the right way to define a mathematical function in Python.  I also don't know what `x1` and `x2` are referring to in MATLAB when converted to Python.

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: Second line should x2

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: It seems that your first and largest problem is that you need to do the necessary work to learn Python language features to support the coding that you want.  "I don't know if this is the right way ..."  *Why* don't you know?  You have many tutorials and a Python interpreter.  If you need beginner tutelage or similar support, please consider posting to a site that handles such traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In Python function definition starts with def keyword followed by function name and arguments in brackets. Also, unlike Matlab, Python uses a 0-based indexing and square brackets for slicing of arrays. So it should be:

```py
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    return np.array([[x1+2*x2-2], [x1**2+4*x2**2-4]])
```